# How to change timestamp to seconds in ESPER

Tags: timestamp, esper

I am new to **esper** and have been trying  to find a way to convert to get current_timestamp in seconds instead of long millisecond.

I use:

```
Select current_timestamp, columnName From Table.win:time_batch(60 sec)
```

for which it gives timestamp in long milliseconds...is there a command or a way to get it in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the English.  I have also marked up your code, this is done by adding 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function already. It is easy to make your own function in Esper. The documentation is under plug-in single row function or user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get by using cast

select cast(current_timestamp.get('hour'), string) || ':' || cast(current_timestamp.get('min'), string) as time

this gave me HH:MM

so problem solved for now.